# How to rip the audio from a video?

Tags: python, video, audio, gstreamer

I am on ubuntu and want to convert a mp4 video to an mp3 audio file but can't figure out how. I tried installing ffmpeg but it failed to encode the mp3. I've read the gstreamer does it but I can't figure out how. I have gstreamer and python installed. I can program with python, but am not super comfortable compiling software from source or any higher level command line stuff. I only know the basics on the command line.

Comment: "it failed to encode the mp3".  Way too vague.  `ffmpeg` can do it.  Please tell us what command you tried, and what error you got.

Comment: Why don't you first learn how to do it manually, with ffmpeg from the command-line, and then either fire a process from python to call ffmpeg, or use it as a library?

Comment: in order to get ffmpeg to work, I would need to build it from source to work with lame, but I don't have the technical skills required to do that. So I am looking for an alternative method that doesn't require building software from source.

Comment: I didn't include the ffmpeg error because I understand the error.

Answer (score 3):

```
mplayer <videofile> -dumpaudio -dumpfile out.bin
```

it will copy the raw audio stream, that should then be easily converted using sox, lame, vlc or whatnot. VLC has nice conversion options as well - and it sports a GUI. I don't know about extracting just the audio, but it should sure be *capable* of it

Answer (score 1):

Use TAE https://github.com/tuna74/TunaAudioExtracter. It does everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

hmm, for an easy python solution, you could always checkout the python video converter, on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/video-converter a sample code is as follows:

```
    from converter import Converter
    c = Converter()
    conv = c.convert('g.mp4', 'clip5.mp3', {'format':'mp3','audio':{'codec': 'mp3','bitrate':'22050','channels':1}})
    for timecode in conv:
        pass
```

where clip5.mp3 is the name of the output file,

Comment: I am getting an error `no module named converter` even after installing it using pip.

Comment: @raptor96 it is important that you use pypi, unpack the thing and install it from there,  pip actually refers to a different library,

Comment: Still same error, downloaded from pypi, unzipped and installed it and it says `no Module named Converter`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this using GStreamer is to create GStreamer pipeline with **decodebin** element using `gst-launch` command-line utility:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=in.mp4 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc ! filesink location=out.mp3
```

In case your mp4 file contains audio track in mp3 format you may want to avoid re-encoding:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=in.mp4 ! qtdemux ! audio/mpeg ! filesink location=out.mp3
```

If you want to use FFMPEG, you can use following command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 out.mp3
```

You can avoid re-encoding (in case audio track is in mp3) with `-acodec copy` option:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -acodec copy out.mp3
```