# How to extract audio from a video file using python?

Tags: python, audio, video, extract

I want to write a python program that could extract audio from a video file (e.g. `video.avi`).
Is there any good library for it? And where should I start from?
I tried to use PyMedia, but I couldn't install it on my MacOSX(Mountain Lion).

**EDIT:**
The problem is `video.avi` is not completely available. Someone is writing on it and adding some frames to it every second. So I wanted to write a code in python to get the video as it comes and extract the audio from it and write it to a file (e.g. `audio.mp3`, `audio.wav`). 
I don't know if `ffmpeg` can wait for the video to be copied to `video.avi`.

And I cannot wait for the video to be copied completely and then do the audio extraction. I have to do it as it comes.

Comment: Is this simply for converting personal files? If so, I would recommend using ffmpeg instead of python. http://superuser.com/questions/268985/ffpmeg-remove-audio-from-video

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5506651/939986

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But it doesn't solve my problem. Please take another look at my question, I edited it and add more information.

Comment: @Mehran Hey, have you got any solution?

Comment: @raptor96 Sorry for late response. But unfortunately I never found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a complete solution, but from the [ffmpeg docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe), it looks like ffmpeg can read an incomplete file by piping to stdin. Example from the docs:

```
cat test.wav | ffmpeg -i pipe:0
```

If you must use python, you can always [call ffmpeg using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741357/4708327).